# Question about Root locus and Nyquist analysis

Tags: control-theory

Currently i m preparing for my control systems exam, and i saw a question about nyquist which asks 'For which K value transfor function is critically stable?' there is function and nyquist plot. So i decided to solve question with root locus too for double check and K i found on root locus plot is different than Nyquist plot and i checked with mathlab too.Did i miss something i thought root locus plot and Nyquist plot suppose to give me same answer.

Thank you for reading..

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an expression of the open-loop transfer function? If so, just try to substitute both $K$ values and chack the closed-loop poles.